# External queue members in Asterisk

Tags: mobile, queue, asterisk, pbx

How do I describe queue members, so that callers would be forwarded, for example, to mobile numbers, e.g:

`queues.conf`

```
[my_queue]
...
;local member
member => SIP/member1
;external member
member => SIP/external-provider/<member2's number> ;but this doesn't work
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use local channel to describe any member, including external number

```
member => Local/12345@default/n
```

Where [default] is  our context.

Also you can use

```
member => SIP/12345@yourprovider
```

Note, that is REALY not so nice idea, becuase it can't get state of number and have call it even if it already speaking.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you!
@arheops, there really isn't a way of getting the state of number? Why?

Comment: Because for state you need CALL it. Or you need save state via GROUP() in dialplan and check it.